# Samsung Gear. Unable to install HelloAccessory project

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I've downloaded macOSX Tizen for wearable sdk, and successfully installed the compiled sample `HelloAccessory`, but when I try to compile source project and try to install, I just receive an "Error installing application" and can't find any related log trace.

After struggling with this longer than I'd like, I figured out this line in the Tizen project config.xml was causing the problem:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/accessoryprotocol"/>
```

Removing it, I can install the application with no errors, but obviously, communication between watch and mobile does not work.

I read this could have something to do with signing certificates, so I followed Tizen sdk manual to generate a certificate request, and today I received `certificate-registration.xml` from Samsung, but still, the problem persists.

After days (maybe weeks), I'm in the edge of insanity. Am I missing something obvious? Anyone succeeded compiling the project samples or at least could point me in the right direction to find the log with a more exhaustive explanation of what's happening?

Comment: Does your AndroidManifest.xml have <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK" /> ?

Comment: Thanks @AndyOS. Yes, all permissions needed are set. I'm just running the `HelloAccessory` sample, so I assume the code is ok. Actually, if I run HelloAccessoryProvider android project with the precompiled `HelloAccessoryConsumer.wgt`, it works. That's why I'm guessing the problem must be somehow in the way I compile `HelloAccessoryConsumer` Tizen project.

Comment: But if you build the consumer yourself, copy the new widget to the provider and try to re-install it fails?

Comment: @AndyOS Exactly. I also do a project cleanup just after copying the new widget, just in case. I have tried re-installing, and installing just after completely deleting the working installed app.

Comment: It does sound like a cert issue then,I couldn't install until I got the cert. You used the watch device id when generating the csr?

Comment: @AndyOS Yes, I did. I thought it could be a cert issue, but I actually can install if I remove the privilege, does it make any sense?

Comment: I think the privilege needs the cert. Perhaps try to get a new cert using the default emulator id and see can you get it to work on the virtual watch.

Comment: Mmh after reviewing everything once, guess I may have missed the last step after registering the certificate. I don't have the device right now, but will check again as soon as I have it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It seems, the last step is optional as author and distribution certificates are automatically created, so I'm still stuck :( Thanks anyway for your help @AndyOS

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that privilege you are using is not public, so you can use it only on emulator, not on actual device (security policy does not allow installing non-public privileged apps that are signed with 'partner' key). 
See thread below for more details:
http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=258928

Comment: Thanks @m.wasowski. I'm aware of that thread, and it says actually having the certificate should work. It works indeed installing the apk that comes packaged out of the box. Could requesting a 'platform' key do the trick?

Comment: If you have developer target with dedicated binary, you can probably download special 'platform' certs (you need both author and distributor). But those won't work on commercial devices - for security reasons. To install widget with non-public privileges you need to have it signed by Tizen Store. See https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/tizen_overview/platform_privileges.htm
However, if you want to install it on Samsung Gear, you should probably go through [Samsung App Certification](http://developer.samsung.com/distribute/app-certification) process

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test with an actual device, you must get a special certificate from Samsung that uses a UUID of your Samsung Gear.

Comment: Yeah I got that. Did you succeeded deploying to real device with `tizen:privilege`?

Comment: Then I may be missing something obvious :( What kind of certificarte did you request?